# Is there a way to install different node version using npm in windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm-windows

Because of our company policies I cannot install nvm on my machine to have multiple node versions. Is there any npm package using which I can install and switch to different versions of node ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you should be able to download the zip version of Node.js, unzip as many versions as you want in different folders, and then use the desired version by specifying the full path to the node.exe that you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

I have a build tool for a proprietary system that needs an old node version.

I just downloaded and unzipped that version into a folder and run a batch script on the console to put the old node as the first `%PATH%` entry. After running the batch script all node calls use the old version

Comment: I have downloaded node and set path using this command 
SET PATH=C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\node8;%PATH%

Now if I run node -v 
8.11.3 



But if I run npm -v then Im getting below error 
"Cannot find module update-notifer"